# Is it suitable to use Core Data in this situation of Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8

I am new to Swift and XCode

I am programming a app which need to store user's information like their name, birthday and telephone. The thing is that it only need to store 1 user's information, but as I see from Core Data, it stores lots of data in same table. (Like lots of user's name and birthday)

So I want to ask if there is a better way to store this information in the app. Thanks!

PS: Sorry for my bad English. :(

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ weighs up the different strategies for persistence

Comment: Awhile back I was looking at using Core Data to store user information for an app I was working on. I'd recommend you take a look at NSUserDefaults instead, as it's a lot simpler to implement for what you want to do. Try taking a look at the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) for quicking storing and retrieving small data like 1 user's info.

**Swift**

```
//Storing data:

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Arefly", forKey: "userNameKey")

//Reading data:

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey")
println(name) ==> Arefly
```

**Objc**

```
//Storing data:

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:"Arefly" forKey:@"userNameKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

//Reading data:

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *name= [defaults stringForKey:@"userNameKey"];
NSLog(name) ==> Arefly
```

Comment: I second that, you would want to use CoreData if you were to store a set of data that would require a structure such as offered by a database. For simple storage of a couple of data, preference system (NSUserDefault) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you have to make a relational table for it in which their will be a unique key  i.e "user_id" that will be unique. Check the link and add a variable of user_id.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial